# redux - асинхронные запросы

Tags: redux

Здравствуйте.

Вот решил поучить redux, и столкнулся с проблемой асинхронной передачи данных.

Вроде понял как получать данные и передавать их в редюсер. Но вот в чем проблема:
Данные в редюсер приходят нормальные, а вот в компоненте получаю какую-то лажу в виде объекта к свойствам которого не могу получить доступ.

Вот мой код:

**action.js**

```js
import {
  SELECT_REDDIT,
  ERROR_REDDIT
} from '../constants/ActionTypes'

export function loadData() {
  return dispatch => fetch('talks.json')
    .then(
      res => res.json()
    )
    .then(
      data => dispatch({ type: SELECT_REDDIT, data }),
      err => dispatch({ type: ERROR_REDDIT, err })
    );
}
```

**reduser**

```js
import { SELECT_REDDIT, ERROR_REDDIT } from '../constants/ActionTypes'

export default function data(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_REDDIT: {
      return Object.assign(state, action.data) // Если делаю Object.assign({}, state, action.data) - приходит пустой объект
    }

    case ERROR_REDDIT: {
      return action.err;
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

**configureStore.js**

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )

  return store
}
```

При выполнении:

```
console.log(data)
```

получаю:

```js
> Object {}
> Object {} // Если развернуть объект
  > main: Object
  > res1: Object
  > res2: Object
  > res3: Object
  > __proto__: Object
```

А вот если выполнить:

```
console.log(data.main)
```

получаю:

> undefined

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так? Или может я где-то накосячил?

PS
Данные с сервера получаю нормальные, в таком виде данные становятся после reduser`a

Comment: что приходит в `action.data` вы проверяли? Остановитесь дебагом в редьюсере перед `Object.assign` и посмотрите почему пустой объект.

Comment: action.data приходит как надо. Есть доступ к свойствам, например action.data.main. А в свойствах компонента уже пустой объект.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте снипеты для кода, который не может быть выполнен на месте.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, где вы делаете `console.log(data)`

Comment: @Виктор пускай он и приходит, что возвращает действие `Object.assign` посмотрите через `debugger`. Прямо по коду точку поставьте и проверьте.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov

constructor( props ) {
    super( props )

    var { data } = props.data
    console.log(data)
}

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев

`export function data(state = {}, action) {`
  `switch (action.type) {`
    `case SELECT_REDDIT: {`
     `debugger;`
      `return Object.assign(state, action.data)`
    `}`

    `default: {`
      `return state;`
    `}`
  `}`
`}`

http://prntscr.com/cmwrwz

Comment: Как форматировать комментарии?

Comment: Не надо их форматировать) Что возвращает вам `Object.assign(state, action.data)`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я ссылку скрина скинул  он возвращает нормальный объект

Comment: @Виктор не надо уточнять ваш вопрос в комментариях, они не для этого. Обратите внимание на кнопку "правка" под вашим вопросом.

Comment: @Виктор мой прокси  такие картинки не открывает, я не вижу. Вы сами должны понять, есть там объект после мержа или нет) И ответ мне должен быть, да или нет)

Comment: )) Да. До return с объектом все в порядке!

Comment: Как я понял, на `Object.assign(state, action.data)` идеи закончились!